# When I start running my proyect spring boot Process finished with exit code 1 and exception Attribute 'proxyBeanMethods'

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

```
2020-04-06 23:49:23.738  INFO 14048 --- [           main] c.s.contacts.ContactsWsApplication       : Starting ContactsWsApplication on Lenovo-PC with PID 14048 (C:\Users\JOSERAMON\IdeaProjects\blog-contacts-ws-parte-3\contacts-ws\target\classes started by JOSERAMON in C:\Users\JOSERAMON\IdeaProjects\blog-contacts-ws-parte-3\contacts-ws)
2020-04-06 23:49:23.746  INFO 14048 --- [           main] c.s.contacts.ContactsWsApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-04-06 23:49:24.558 ERROR 14048 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationConfigurationException: Attribute 'proxyBeanMethods' in annotation [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication] is declared as an @AliasFor nonexistent attribute 'proxyBeanMethods' in annotation [org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration].; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration.proxyBeanMethods()
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils$AliasDescriptor.<init>(AnnotationUtils.java:2180) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils$AliasDescriptor.from(AnnotationUtils.java:2148) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils$AliasDescriptor.getOtherDescriptors(AnnotationUtils.java:2312) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils$AliasDescriptor.getAttributeAliasNames(AnnotationUtils.java:2299) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.getAttributeAliasNames(AnnotationUtils.java:1813) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.getAttributeAliasMap(AnnotationUtils.java:1722) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.postProcessAnnotationAttributes(AnnotationUtils.java:1335) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.getMergedAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:365) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:121) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.attributesFor(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:285) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:93) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:72) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.doRegisterBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:224) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.registerBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:145) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.register(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:135) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:158) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:135) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:127) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.load(SpringApplication.java:717) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:392) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sinbugs.contacts.ContactsWsApplication.main(ContactsWsApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration.proxyBeanMethods()
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2130) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils$AliasDescriptor.<init>(AnnotationUtils.java:2173) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

My pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sinbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>contacts-ws</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>contacts-ws</name>
    <description>Servicio web REST simple</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
            <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>


    </project>
```

A lot of thanks

Answer (score 0):

Updating all your `org.springframework.boot` dependencies and parent to same version   `2.2.6.RELEASE` should solve your problem.